# iphone xcode project navigator alphabetical order

Tags: iphone, xcode

Any one know how to get xcode to list the project navigator files in alphabetical order?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per Apple](https://devforums.apple.com/message/395169), this is a known omission from Xcode and will probably be re-added in a future release. If you would like it to be re-added faster, please [file a bug report](http://bugreporter.apple.com). Until then, your best bet is to open the project in Xcode 3 and use the sort there, or do it manually.

Answer (score -1):

Select the project in the Groups and Files pane.

[image]

In the list pane (upper right) click on File Name, which should sort them by file name.
[image]

And of course, you can filter this list in the search bar on the top right.

[image]

Comment: These are alternative sorting methods outside of the navigator, not sorting of the project navigator which is the original question.